# Find $f\in L^p(0,1)$, but $f\notin L^q(0,1)$, $p < q$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

I want to find a measurable function $f \in L^p(0,1)$, for $p\in [1,+\infty)$, but $f \notin L^q(0,1)$ for each $q\in (p,+\infty]$.

I tried to manipulate $f=\frac{1}{x^a}$, improving the exponent $a$ s.t. $\int_0^1 |\frac{1}{x^a}|^p d\mu < \infty $, but since $p,q$ are real number, I cannot find anything - I don't know how to say it properly, but I cannot find an explicit expression s.t. some algebraic tricks make appear something smaller or bigger than 1, which is the limit point for the divergence and the convegercence of the function-  (otherwise, if we deal with the integers I found $ f=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{q-1}{p^2}}} $, where $q \geq p$ )

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that $\int_0^1 \frac {1}{x^\alpha}<\infty$ if and only if $\alpha<1$. Can you find an $a$ such that $ap<1$ and $aq\geq1$ for $p<q$?

Comment: sorry, but shouldn't your first condition be also equal? $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^\alpha} < \infty $ iff $\alpha \leq 1$. Anyway I'll try to think about it a bit more

Comment: No, because we have $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} = \infty$. More precisely $\int_\varepsilon^1 \frac{1}{x} = log(1)-log(\varepsilon) \rightarrow \infty$ as $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$.

Comment: sorry, i misread, my fault ;)

Comment: You can find an $a$ such that $ap>1$ and $aq>1$ if you want, but there is a very simple $a$ for the case $ap<1$ and $aq\geq1$. I'll let you find it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
(x \log^2 x)^{-1/p}, &\text{if}\ x\in (0,1/2),\\
0, &\text{if}\ x \in (1/2, 1).
\end{cases}
$$